# How to put many inputs under one array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the POST array I am getting. I have a requirement that for 15 dishes each dish will have its own lunch & lunch quantity and dinner & dinner quantity.

i .e.

```
Dish1  lunch  quantity   dinner    quantity
```

I want to Dish1 and its needed inputs under one array so that i can store it seprerately for specific dish.

But the problem is I can't name 'lunch', 'lunch_qty', 'dinner', dinner_qty with same name.

This is the post array am getting. I have named 'lunch' and 'dinner' checkbox as 'type' .

```
Array ( 
    [dish] => Array ( 
                    [0] => BENGAN BHARTA 
                    ) 
    [type] => Array ( 
                    [0] => lunch 
                    [1] => dinner 
                    ) 
    [lunch_qty] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 12 
                    ) 
    [dinner_qty] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 2 
                    ) 
    )
```

Required result

```
Array ( 
    [dish] => Array ( 
            [0] => BENGAN BHARTA 

    [dish0_type] => Array ( 
            [0] => lunch 
            [1] => dinner 
            ) 
    [dish0lunch_qty] => Array ( 
            [0] => 12 
            ) 
    [dish0dinner_qty] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2 
            ) 
)
```

Please understand i want to associate each dish and its lunch, dinner, lunch_qty, dinner_qty

This is my code, i have written to insert it into database,But i am ended into inserting redundant values

```
$post_data=$this->input->post();

$count=count(array_filter($_POST));

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $dish=$post_data['dish'][$i];
    $dessert=$post_data['dessert'];
    $type=$post_data['type'][$i];
    $pulav=$post_data['pulav'];
    $rice=$post_data['rice'];
    $chapati=$post_data['chapati'];
    $lunch_qty=$post_data['lunch_qty'][$i];
    $dinner_qty=$post_data['dinner_qty'][$i];

    $qry="INSERT INTO alacarte 
            (dish,rice,pulav,chapati,dessert,type,lunch_qty,dinner_qty) 
        VALUES ('".$dish."','".$rice."','".$pulav.
                "','".$chapati."','".$dessert."','".$type.
                "','".$lunch_qty."','".$dinner_qty."') ";

    $query=$this->db->query($qry);

}
```

Comment: Please show an example of the required result array

Comment: What do you mean by `Dish1`? The is only one `Dish` in the array

Comment: Array ( 
    [dish] => Array ( 
                    [0] => BENGAN BHARTA 
                    ) 
    [dish0_type] => Array ( 
                    [0] => lunch 
                    [1] => dinner 
                    ) 
    [dish0lunch_qty] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 12 
                    ) 
    [dish0dinner_qty] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 2 
                    ) 
    )               Please understand i want to associate each dish and its lunch,dinner,lunch_qty,dinner_qty

Comment: Actually there are 15 dishes,each have different input fields , i just showed dish1....

Comment: Well you are going to have to loop over the first array and create the new array as you go. SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___We fix your attempts, we do not write your code___

Comment: Also, the array you say you want is a very poor representation of the data. It would be very difficult to use once you have created it. Maybe a quick rethink at this point would be a good idea.

Comment: i did't get your last remark

Comment: Well YOU are going to have to foreach loop over the first array and create the new array as you go.

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: You would get better results if you redesigned your database. Look for a Relational Database Design Tutorial. Your current design is just going to cause you problem after problem